# netlogo issues with generating network

Tags: networking, netlogo

when I try to generate a network it looks like this: [image], this happens even when I try to implement very simple code e.g.

```
 let num_neighbors 10

  create-turtles 100

  layout-circle turtles (world-width / 2 - 1)

  ask turtles [create-links-with n-of num_neighbors other turtles]
```

which works in other models (e.g. looks like this[image]). any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: Turn off wrapping:
https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#topology